# How can I record the screen and the rear camera on an iPhone simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, screen-capture, camera, screen-recording

I've seen many apps that can record the iPhone screen and the front camera (facecam) into a single video. It embeds the facecam into a corner of the iPhone screen recording.

I want an app to record the rear camera and combine the video/overlay the video with the screen recording.

Basically I want to make a video showing how a WiFi light bulb reacts when using the iPhone app (screen controls).
So as I record the screen of the iPhone showing the changing the settings of the bulb on the app, I want to use the rear camera to simultaneously record and embed into the screen recording what's happening with the bulb in real time.

The key here is the rear camera, there are software which use the front camera (facecam) and screen recording at the same time but I can't find any app (or a way) to use the rear camera and the screen recording at the same time.

Is this something apps can do on the iPhone with iOS?

Comment: Are you looking for an app to do this or how to develop and app with these capabilities?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this using a single app (preferably) or combination of apps, not to develop one.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve edited this so it reads clearly as a software recommendation. My hunch is Apple doesn’t deliver an SDK or API to do this, but let’s see if the answer isn’t just “no”

Comment: Can you name one app which does screen and cam together?

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of an app that allows overlaying screen recording and a rear camera recording simultaneously (odd why the app makers didn't provide an option to select the rear camera instead of just the front facing camera), here is a workaround I found.

1. Record the screen recording using the iOS screen recorder
2. Record the rear camera video using the iOS camera app
3. Download iMovie from the App Store and overlay the two recordings together (split, picture in picture etc).

Here is a video tutorial I found on YouTube which explains how to combine/overlay two recordings/videos using iMovie on iOS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_qx75zTjr0

I'm not marking this as the answer as this is not my ideal scenario, it would have been nice to have an app do it, but it's a workaround for now.

Comment: This is an excellent post production workflow. I’ve seen multiple devices (iPad for editing) and two devices for capture to reduce the number of “takes”

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn’t possible, you’ll need to mount two phones side by side or atop each other on a stand and record video from one, screen on the other and combine the streams in post-production.

I’ve seen this done many times for marketing / training videos. My hunch is the hardware is capable of this resource wise, but the API isn’t out to do it yet from Apple for apps to ship.

The virtual reality overlays might be how you would need to make this sort of app so that the camera is shown on the screen as you tap and operate controls.